# default click on first element in ng-click angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written below piece of code for clicking the first element in ng-repeat to make it active by default :

```
<ul id="thumbnails">
        <li ng-repeat="thumbnail in thumbnails  | filter:query" ng-switch on='$first' data-ng-click="toggleObject.item = $index" >
            <div data-ng-class="{'active' : toggleObject.item == $index}" ng-switch-when='true' ng-click="getHdImage(thumbnail.IMAGE_ID)">
                <img id="imageViewContainer" ng-src="{{thumbnail.PATH_SMALL}}"/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

controller :

```
        imageView.getViewsByGroupId($stateParams.groupid)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.thumbnails = data;
                        $scope.toggleObject = {item: -1};
                        console.log($scope);
        });
```

So that i could use this active class for making the background color as red. but the default click on first element is not happening. though clicking manually works just fine.

What i am doing wrong here.

Comment: use ng-repeats $first instead. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **$first** scope variable that **ng-repeat** places in scope for you.

Also you can use **ng-init** to make some initialization.

```html
<ul id="thumbnails">
  <li ng-repeat="thumbnail in thumbnails  | filter:query" data-ng-click="toggleObject.item = $index">
    <div data-ng-class="{'active' : $first}" ng-init="$first && getHdImage(thumbnail.IMAGE_ID)" ng-click="getHdImage(thumbnail.IMAGE_ID)">
      <img id="imageViewContainer" ng-src="{{thumbnail.PATH_SMALL}}" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qvl9x9JZkvZ4VW3OSNYk) little plunker that demo's it.

Comment: default class for $first is happening but default click is not happening, which is actually my concern. on click i have a function to call.

Comment: you can use **ng-init** to initialize a property, I'll add that to the example. :)

Comment: yeah, i tried it and its working, but i am still not able to understand the problem with ng-switch

Comment: that's because you didn't do it right, you it should be **ng-switch="$first"**

Comment: I updated the answer, you shouldn't need ng-switch unless you need to do a switch on what you show in the list.

Comment: If you are trying to do that and having issues with it, it would probably be better to ask a question specific to that. :)